# Closed extensions in the weak* topology

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\ell^\infty$ be the Banach space of bounded sequences with the usual norm. and let $\ell_0(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n$, for convergent sequences. Show that the sett L consisting of all continuous extensions of $\ell_0$ to $\ell^\infty$ is closed in the weak* topology on $(\ell^\infty)'$.

The extension is done by Hahn-Banach, but how do I show that something is closed in the weak*? Can I use sequentially closed here? are the topology metriceble?
I can show that this is not a Hilbert space. Is it reflexive?
Im a little bit unsure about all this weak* stuff, 
Please help me out and merry christmas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show $L$ is weak-* closed, you want to show that its complement is weak-* open, i.e. any $\phi \in (\ell^\infty)' \backslash L$ has a weak-* neighborhood disjoint from $L$.
In fact, if $\phi \in (\ell^\infty)' \backslash L$ there is some sequence $s$ that converges to a limit $m$ that is not $\phi(s)$. Consider
 $\{\psi \in (\ell^\infty)': |\psi(s) - \phi(s)|<\epsilon\}$.

Comment: Great, I did not know this was the way to solve it, but how do I know that the set is open? Since the $\psi$ do not converge to m either?

Comment: What is the definition of the weak-* topology?

Comment: The topology that makes all the linear functionals on the form $x(u) = u(x)$ continuous?

Comment: Not quite: it's the weakest topology that does that.  But  $\psi \to \psi(s)$ being continuous is all you need to show that
$\{\psi: |\psi(s) - \phi(s)|<\epsilon\}$ is open.

Comment: but $\psi$ is continuous right? so we are done?

Comment: The continuity of $\psi$ is not an issue here.  The map $\psi \to \psi(s)$ is continuous (because that's what the weak-* topology says is continuous), so we are done.

Comment: I dont get any of that, how does continuity of $s^*:(l^\infty)'\to \mathbb{R}$ at $\psi$ prove that $\psi\not\in L$?

Comment: $\{\psi \in (\ell^\infty)': |\psi(s) - \phi(s)| < \epsilon\} = \{\psi \in (\ell^\infty)': s^*(\psi) \in (\phi(s)-\epsilon, \phi(s) + \epsilon)\}$ is an open set in the weak-* topology.  If $|m - \phi(s)|>\epsilon$, where $m = \lim_n s_n$, that implies $\psi(s) \ne m$, so $\psi \notin L$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, THX